# Debugging an intermittently unresponsive USB device

Tags: usb

My app communicates with a simple USB device as follows:

The app sends commands (2 or 3 bytes each) to the USB device by using WriteFile (kernel32.dll).

For each command that is send, the USB device sends a short response, which the PC receives using ReadFile (kernel32.dll).

Reading and writing is done asynchronously, using GetOverlappedResult to check the status of an operation.

Testing on 2 out of 3 PCs, the app and device function perfectly: all responses are received 100% reliably.

Under identical tests on the third PC, approximately 50% of the ReadFile requests do not return any data - the status remains as pending (ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE) forever.

In other words, approximately for every 2 commands sent, one response is received.

Because the device functions perfectly with the other PCs, it lead me to believe that the problem might be occuring inside Windows, in the underlying code which is called by ReadFile (I presume some lower level USB driver code).

Question:
Please could you advise what debugging tool is most useful to investigate this? With my current knowledge, the internal workings of ReadFile are quite opaque.

The PC which is experiencing the issue is running Windows 8.0

Comment: What device is it and what drivers (.sys) files does it use?  That could make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). Run as admin.

Go to "**Capture**", enable "**Capture Kernel**", enable "**Enable Verbose Kernel Output**".

This might help to investigate errors on Kernel level, if any occured.